# DirectX ID3DXEFFECT::BeginPass()/EndPass() problems

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, effects, directx-9

I am using DirectX 9 w/effects on 3D models. I have loaded all models and effects correctly and have rendered skinned mesh using this method with no problems in the past...however, I recently began to use DXUT with my project. Now, with DXUT, when I try to render a skinned mesh with effects problems are occuring. I have tracked the problem down but don't know how to fix it. The following code occurs during the call to DrawMeshContainer( LPD3DXMESHCONTAINER pMeshContainer ). The problem is the calls to BeginPass()/EndPass(). All meshes that use this effect render properly, but when I try to render objects that do not use the effect, they render completely black color...you can see the object however there is no color. I checked the lighting state before and after render calls to the objects but that seems to be in order. Here is the code for problem lines. If I comment those lines out, the other objects render correctly

```
for(DWORD iAttrib = 0; iAttrib < numAttributes; ++iAttrib)
{
...
DWORD numPasses = 0;
g_pEffect->Begin(&numPasses D3DFX_DONOTSAVESTATE); // writing from memory...2nd param may use different identifier

for(DWORD iPass = 0; iPass < numPasses; ++iPass)
{
g_pEffect->BeginPass(iPass); // Begin Problem

pMeshContainer->MeshData.pMesh->DrawSubset( iAttrib );

g_pEffect->EndPass(); // End Problem
}
g_pEffect->End();

m_d3ddev->SetVertexShader( NULL );

}
}
```

Does BeginPass()/EndPass() cause a state change of some type that I need to account for? I also tried using g_pEffect->CommitChanges() above the call to ID3DXMESH::DrawSubset() with no success...any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

problem fixed...i had to set the pixel shader to NULL along with the vertex shader at the end of the process:

```
m_d3ddev->SetPixelShader( NULL )...
```